# angularjs.forEach second iteration fails to set object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have the following object with nesting array:

```
var foobar = {
        "foo1": ["bar1", "bar2"],
        "foo2": ["bar3", "bar4"]
        }
```

I need to convert it to:

```
{
    "foo1": {"bar1":"bar1", "bar2":"bar2"},
    "foo2": {"bar3":"bar3", "bar4":"bar4"}
}
```

The function below iterates through the first element of the object successfully:

```
$scope.regonal = {};

angular.forEach(foobar, function(value, key) {
    angular.forEach(value, function(v) {

        $scope.regonal[key][v] = v;

    });
});
```

... but fails on the second with error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'bar3' of undefined

Comment: where does `foo3` magically appear from? Is that a typo?

Comment: sorry, typo, corrected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.regonal` is an empty object, that means that the result of
`$scope.regonal[key]` will be undefined. Trying to access `$scope.regonal[key]["bar3"]` means you try to access and set the key bar3 on undefined.

try this:

```
$scope.regonal = {};

angular.forEach(foobar, function(value, key) {
    $scope.regonal[key] = {};
    angular.forEach(value, function(v) {
        $scope.regonal[key][v] = v;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You get error because `$scope.regonal[key]` (there is not any property in `$scope.regonal` with keys `foo1` and `foo2`) is `undefined`, you should set it as empty object,

```js
var foobar = {
  "foo1": ["bar1", "bar2"],
  "foo2": ["bar3", "bar4"]
};

var $scope = {}; // just for example 

$scope.regonal = {};

angular.forEach(foobar, function(value, key) {
  $scope.regonal[key] = {};

  angular.forEach(value, function(v) {
    $scope.regonal[key][v] = v;
  });
});

console.log($scope.regonal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(key in foobar){
    $scope.regional[key] = foobar[key].reduce(function(obj, curr){
        obj[curr] = curr;
        return obj;        
    },{});    
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m54emscg/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

$scope.regonal[key] returns undefined because there is no key named foo1 or foo 2 in regonal. You can create keys by either $scope.regonal[key]={} or $scope.regonal.key={}